# Ionic 2 : I got rejection because "YouTube videos in my app continue to play after pressing power button"

Tags: html, youtube, ionic2, ionic3, youtube-data-api

How can I solve the problem of "YouTube videos in my app continue to play after pressing power button"

I checked so many ways but nothing works fine with ionic

here my HTML code:

```
<iframe class="frame"
    [src]="vidURL+vidOptions | youtube" frameborder="0"  
    webkitallowfullscreen 
    mozallowfullscreen 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```